# Loading list of complex custom object in android

Tags: android, performance, dynamic, rendering

- I have a list of custom object say "Components" contains Component.
- Component also can have list of Component as a member in it.
- Component has type like Table, Date, Time Paragraph, Single Line.
- Depending on type I have to inflating different layout according to
  UI.
- If size of Component list is large then, loading all the Component
  will take type also it will  lead to OutOfMemory exception.

How should I avoid OutOfMemory exception and improve loading time?

Comment: use of universal loader ...

Comment: use of smooth scrolls enabled